# App Engine entity groups: grouping all of a user's data vs avoiding them as long as possible

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working on a web application that allows users to create simple websites and publish them on a static web host, and I have problems deciding if and how I should use ancestors in the gray area between necessary and avoidable.

The model is rather simple: currently every `User` has one or more `Website` entities. The `Website` entities store all the basic information about a website, plus it's nested navigation menu that refers to `Page` entities (the navigation tree is stored as a JSON property). The `Page` entity types are based on a PolyModel, and there are several page types that behave differently (There's a `GalleryPage`, for example).

There are no entity groups (or rather, no entities with ancestors) as of yet, and I'll only need a couple of transactions. When updating a Page's name, for example, I have to update it in the `Page` entity itself as well as in the navigation tree on the `Website` entity.

I think I understand how entity groups work and the basic implications of using them, but I have trouble deciding on the "best" way to structure my data in the absence of strong reasons for either approach. I could:

1. Go entirely without ancestors on my entities. As far as I understand I can still use cross-group transactions as long as I get the entities by key and don't need more than 5 within the transaction. The downside is that I'd depend on the XG transactions and there might come a point where I can't ninja my way around using ancestor queries anymore (and then it might be too late).
2. Make the user object the parent of all his Website's, Page's and other data. This would give the user a strongly consistent view of all of his data, allow me to use transactions whenever I add a feature that would need them, but limits the sustained writes to 1-5/sec. But, as a user will only ever be updating his own data, this might actually work and behave just the same for 1000 users as it will for 1.
3. Try to use even smaller entity groups (like seperating the navigation from the `Website` and making that the parent of the Website's Pages). But I'm not quite sure if there's much benefit to this, because most of the editing happens on Pages anyway.

So I guess the real question is: how do you decide when to use ancestor relationships on App Engine when there's no obvious reason for or against them? Would you go for the convenience of strongly consistent queries and being able to use transactions freely while adding features later, or would you avoid them at all costs until there's a very obvious reason for them, even if might limit my ability to do transactions later?

I read the related documentation, read the chapter on transactions in "Programming App Engine", looked at quite a few of the Google I/O videos, but I still find it hard to make that decision.

Comment: You might want to consider using namespaces , one for each user or site.  Remember if everything is based on gets you will always have a strongly consistent view.  Lack of of an ancestor doesn't preclude transactions just limits the scope.

Comment: @TimHoffman I haven't really read into namespaces much yet, but I assumed that they're for broader grouping of data and something I'd maybe start to use when I need seperate testing data, or entirely different groups of users. I'll read into them. And yeah, I do use gets mostly. One example where I don't is on GalleryPages to get the Images. This is one of the examples where I need to insert the uploaded image via Javascript because it might not be there on the next request.

Comment: Namespaces would ensure that each user could not access another users site.  Reduces the potential of bugs allowing incorrect access to resources.   Not sure I follow you image in gallery page bit.  I have a basic CMS based site (used pretty much the same code for the last few years).  Only ever edited by one or two users.  Transactional updates used.  Galleries etc...  (python, ndb , pyramid, deform based), no ancestors used at all. Some queries for gallery/listing, but gets for tree walking.

Comment: Remember you have cross group transactions too.

Comment: Great question.  There isn't a "right" way, and you've hit upon a key deficiency in the App Engine datastore - you have to know the transactional operations that are coming before you start building your app.  That being said, #2 sounds like the safest bet, leaving you the most options in the future.

Comment: @TimHoffman Upps, the "GalleryPage" bit was a bit confusing, wasn't it? I just meant to say: I use mostly get entities by reference/key, but I also have a couple of queries that should also be consistent from a users point of view. And the first example that came to mind was a user uploading a picture to a GalleryPage. I query for the images, and a user will expect a newly uploaded picture to be there on the next refresh. I can use some Javascript trickery to insert it into the page without actually refreshing the page, but still, edits should always look consistent, otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: @dragonx Yeah, I think I'll pick option #2 and make each individual user the parent of his Websites, Pages, and their content. This is where most of the editing happens and the part that will only ever be seen/interactively updated by a single user (per account) and one page at a time. Should I add a feature that requires a ton of writes/updates, I can still do that outside of the group. Seems easier to me that having to work around consistency and transaction issues from day 1 without any clear benefit. Thanks.